# reliably detecting line breaks in php

Tags: php

I'm going to build a wee batch search field where someone can enter/paste in a bunch of keywords separated by a linebreak, they might be copied in from excel, word or where-ever.

So I plan to use php to explode() that input and loop through it for an SQL search.

Do I need to do anything special to reliably detect the line breaks - my understanding is that the character can be different depending on where it's pasted from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on where you got the string from, it's either \n, \r, or \r\n. If you explode on both \r and \n (and ignore empty matches), you should be fine.